# Lorentz transformation for stars

Tags: special-relativity, cepheids

If a star that has regular pulses(standard candle) is flying away from us at relativistic velocity(very distant), would that pulses look like very sluggish compared to a non-relativistic velocity(close to earth)...something like a clock ticking in a relativistic spaceship and....... ofcourse red-shifted.Thanks.

Comment: I am not very sure, what you ask. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Wikipedia has a detailed page on [red shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift) and it's causes.  Light already has a "built in" pulse - it has a wavelength.

Comment: @peterh He means something like Cepheids; will their frequency change?

Comment: Is this the same for a super nova in the sense that its explosion will last more fore an observer with a relativistic difference in velocities regards the star.Hubble law says more distant a nova is the more its speed.So more speed away from us more slower the picture of its explosion because of Lorentz law..(?)

Comment: @JankoBradvica -- Yes. In fact, time dilation of Type Ia supernova light curves (and even the temporal evolution of their spectra) has been observed numerous times.

Comment: It's not a Lorentz time dilation, though. It's general relativistic, but the result is the same $(1+z)$ factor as _if_ it were special relativity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They would if we could see them far enough away, but cepheid variables are only visible up to about 20 million light years distant. That may sound like a long way, but in astronomical terms it is nearby.

Comment: 20 Mlyr is still enough to see a time dilation of 0.5%.